# How can I get the user details in Auth0 using SvelteKit on the server side

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, auth0, sveltekit

I am trying to authenticate a user with Auth0 service using SvelteKit, on the server side but keep getting the error `invalid_token`, `cannot read properties of undefined`:

```
outer {
  error: 'invalid_token',
  errorDescription: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'XMLHttpRequest')"
}
```

The login endpoint:

```
import * as auth0 from "auth0-js";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export async function post({ request }) {

        const body = await request.json();
        const hash = body.hash;
        console.log("Sign-in.ts", hash);

        // Initialize the Auth0 application
        var webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
            domain: '<domain>',
            clientID: '>clientid>'
        });
        // Parse the URL and extract the Access Token
        webAuth.parseHash({hash: hash, state: "rtre4", nonce: "er324"}, function (err, authResult) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("outer", err);
            }
            
            webAuth.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function (innerErr, user) {
                // This method will make a request to the /userinfo endpoint
                // and return the user object, which contains the user's information,
                // similar to the response below.
                if (innerErr) {
                    return console.log("inner", innerErr);
                    
                }

                console.log(user);
            });
        });

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                message: "OK"
            }
        };
};
```

I can successfully log the user in and redirect the user to my /login route with the access and id tokens as hash in the url.
Next I am trying to get the user details. I want to get the user details in the server, so I send the complete hash to my `/api/login.ts` endpoint with a `POST` request, and call the `auth0-js` function `parseHash` in the server endpoint, which fails. The same code works on the client-side, though.

The landing page:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(async () => {
        const hash = window.location.hash;
        const response = await fetch("/api/sign-in", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    hash: hash
                })
            });
            console.log(response);
    });
</script>
<div class="content">
    <p>Redirecting, please wait...</p>
</div>
```

Therefore I am thinking either the cookie somehow changes during stringifying it, or Sveltekit does not have XmlHttpRequest, but does anyone has further insight?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"...or Sveltekit does not have XmlHttpRequest"_ - That should be easy to determine with the help of your preferred search provider.

Comment: ok so apparently `XmlHttpRequest` is a browser feature that does not exist in server. well thanks for the clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas's comments, I realized that `XmlHttpRequest` is a browser feature that does not exist in a server. For this reason, I have implemented a manual request to the Auth0 endpoint using the token I get from the page to get the user details:

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export async function post({ request }) {

    /**
     * auth0.WebAuth does not work on server side because it uses XmlHttpRequest, which is unavailable on server
     */
        const body = await request.json();
        const token = body.accessToken;
        const response = await fetch("https://<app Auth0 address>/userinfo", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`},
        });

        const userData = await response.json();
        console.log(userData);
        };
};
```

I am still calling the method `webAuth.parseHash` in the client-side where auth0.js works, because this method also validates the tokens automatically. After validation, I am `POST`ing the access token to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JWT token in your cookies you can decode the JWT cookie to get the user information
You can do that like this:

```
import * as cookie from 'cookie';
import Buffer from 'buffer';
export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {

    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    if(!cookies.id_token) {
       
        return await resolve(event);
    }
    
    const base64Payload = cookies.id_token.split('.')[1];
    const decodedJWTToken = base64Payload ? Buffer.Buffer.from(base64Payload, 'base64') : '';
    event.locals.user = decodedJWTToken ? JSON.parse(decodedJWTToken.toString()) : null

    const response =  await resolve(event);
    return response

};

export function getSession({ locals }) {
    return {
        user: locals.user && {
            nickname: locals.user.nickname ? locals.user.nickname : null,
            email: locals.user.email ? locals.user.email : null,
            sub: locals.user.sub ? locals.user.sub : null,
            email_verified: locals.user.email_verified ? locals.user.email_verified : null,
            picture: locals.user.picture ? locals.user.picture : null,
        }
    };
}
```